# Apparently same MySQL subquery behaves different when used as condition inside a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, where-clause

I have this two querys that I think should behave the same way but they do not.

Query 1 (Always return empty):

```sql
SELECT * FROM code
WHERE id = (
                SELECT id FROM code
                WHERE available = 1
                ORDER BY rand()
                LIMIT 1
    )
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

Query 2 (Return one random row where `available = 1`):

```sql
SELECT * FROM code
WHERE id = (
        SELECT rc.id FROM
            (
                SELECT id FROM code
                WHERE available = 1
                ORDER BY rand()
                LIMIT 1
            ) as rc
    )
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

If I run the subquerys independently they behave the same (Return one random row where `available = 1`)

Example:

```sql
SELECT rc.id FROM
(
  SELECT id FROM code
  WHERE available = 1
  ORDER BY rand()
  LIMIT 1
) as rc;

-- returns 1 row
--
--       id
-- 1 <random_id>
```

```sql
  SELECT id FROM code
  WHERE available = 1
  ORDER BY rand()
  LIMIT 1

-- returns 1 row
--
--       id
-- 1 <random_id>
```

Table `code` definiton:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `code` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `available` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I tried both querys but get empty result for the first query and the second gives the expected result. As far as i know they should return the same result, what I am missing?

Comment: Looks odd. By `independent` do you mean different connections? Which MariaDB version? What does `show engine innodb status\G` show? How does it behave different without `SKIP LOCKED`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mariadb create function returning random id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431483/mariadb-create-function-returning-random-id)

Comment: Thank you @GeorgRichter you are correct. Apparently the UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY is the problem. When using another level of subquery it generates a temporary table and the UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY is executed over this temporary table that holds the random value. That's why the "Query 2" works. I don't fully understand the subquery caching mechanism. Will look for some docs about it.

Answer (score 0):

As @GeorgRichter mentioned in comments section the apparently extrange behaviour of Query 1 is due to subquery caching mechanism. You can read about it in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431483/mariadb-create-function-returning-random-id) shared by Georg.

As you can see in the following EXPLAIN statements when using another level of subquery it generates a temporary table and the UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY is executed over a temporary table that holds the random value. That's why the "Query 2" works as expected and "Query 1" does not.

EXPLAIN for "Query 1":

[image: EXPLAIN for "Query 1":]

EXPLAIN for "Query 2":

[image: EXPLAIN for "Query 2"]

I don't know if "Query 1" can be fixed, to behave as "Query 2" without adding another level of subquery, but the main purpose of this question was to understand them and why they behave different. Thanks to @GeorgRichter for pointing me in the correct direction.

EDIT:
Another [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187672/2213998) on this matter

JUST A LITTLE REFLEXION:
As the previous shared posts indicate the RAND() subquery in "Query 1" is executed once for each row in `code` table, so exists a probability that the query returns one or multiple rows when this random picked id equals the current row being compared. The probability of each row with `available=1` to be picked by the query is `1/TOTAL_AVAILABLE_ROWS` and the probability of this query to return `n` rows is `(1/TOTAL_AVAILABLE_ROWS)^n`

I think this approach using a `common table expression` is more performant

```sql
WITH random_code AS (
    SELECT id FROM code
    WHERE available = 1
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT * FROM code
JOIN random_code
WHERE code.id = random_code.id
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

EXPLAIN:

[image: Explain using common table expression]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Don't know how to export EXPLAIN result in a readable way :/